# How to get iCloud image URL in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud

I am using SwiftAssetsPickerController for fetching images from photo library and iCloud. It provides all images, But those images which are stored in iCloud, do not provide image URL. I need iCloud image URL. So how can I get iCloud images URL?

Comment: @Moritz Which system are available?. Could you provide some content for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
import MobileCoreServices

func setDocumentPicker() {
    let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeJPEG as String], in: .import)
    importMenu.delegate = self
    importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

after that you have to call the delegate method of **DocumentPicker**

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    print("URL= \(url)")
}
```

**NOTE:** You must have to signed in with iCloud account in your device because you can not access iCloud files directly, and you have to enable iCloud functionality in **capabilities** in also enable & configure in App ID on apple developer account